# excel dna addins how pack unmanaged dll in xll file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel-dna

I want use ml.net to make Excel function
ml.net in .NET framework classics need one unmanaged dll ...
when I manually copy dll in debug folder all work great .
excel DNA not support unmanaged dll that not contain in reference folder ...
how I pack unmanaged dll and pack in xll file ?

Comment: You should look at the excel dna samples on github.  Here's a link to one about packing that should help:  https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/Packing/PackDep/PackDep.dna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel-DNA packing does not currently support packing of unmanaged DLLs, thus you won't be able to use the built-in packaging mechanism (i.e. `ExcelDnaPack`) to pack the ml.net unmanaged DLL.

As a workaround, you can add the ml.net unmanaged DLL as an embedded resource in your .NET assembly, and then extract it to disk at the start of your add-in, before any of the code that uses the DLL had the chance to run.

You then would call `LoadLibrary` yourself to load that unmanaged DLL into the process.

Some useful links for reference:

- [Pack NMath into .xll file #332](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/332)
- [ExcelDnaPack: Add support for packing any kind of resource #331](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/331)
- [32/64 bit builds with different dependencies #329](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/329)
- [Using sqlcompact with how excel-dna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190410/211672)
- [Excel DNA with ILNumerics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30876494/211672)